# Problem with adding image files to my server

Tags: php

Basically, I am trying to put an image file into a folder in my server and add the *dir* in MYSQL BD. It successfully puts the file into the folder and adds the path link to the row in the table.
Now, the problem: when I try to download the file and show it, it downloads but nothing shows, so I check the file in the FTP and it turns out the file size is 0.1kb. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

I've done some research on the issue and I might be crazy but I think I'm the only one having this issue because I couldn't get help anywhere.

here's my code;

```
$ImageData = $_POST['image_data'];
$ImageName = date("D M d, G:i");
$ImagePath = "albums/$ImageName.jpg";
$UploadPath =  __DIR__."/../".$ImagePath;

$img = $ImagePath; //to be inserted into DB row

//mysql ("INSERT INTO table...") query here

if($InsertSQL->rowCount()){
    file_put_contents($UploadPath,base64_decode($ImageData));
    // file_put_contents($UploadPath,$ImageData);
    echo "Your Image Has Been Uploaded.";
}
```

N/B: I use base64_decode because I encoded it from android.

I expect the file to save to the server dir with the actual size.

Comment: `$ImageData` Where is that defined

Comment: Your image doesn't exists of an actual image, it is just the date

Comment: Edited. sorry (I forgot to add it)

Comment: Files dont get uploaded in the `$_POST` array look at the `$_FILES` array ! [See manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are stored in `$_FILES` not `$_POST`.

Assuming that the field in your form is called `image_data`

```
$ImageTmpPath = file_get_contents($_FILES['image_data']['tmp_name']);
$ImageName = date("D M d, G:i");
$ImagePath = "albums/$ImageName.jpg";
$UploadPath =  __DIR__."/../".$ImagePath;

$img = $ImagePath; //to be inserted into DB row

//mysql ("INSERT INTO table...") query here

if($InsertSQL->rowCount()){
    file_put_contents($UploadPath,base64_decode($ImageTmpPath));
    echo "Your Image Has Been Uploaded.";
}
```

Comment: Assuming `image_data` is the correct field name from the form then you will want `file_get_contents($_FILES['image_data']['tmp_name'])`

Comment: You are most certainly right

Comment: Still putting the file at ```0.1kb```

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @RiggsFolly and @Rust, files are actually stored with $_FILES not $_POST
but what actually solved my issue was the
`file_put_contents($UploadPath,base64_decode($ImageData));`

it is supposed to be 
`move_uploaded_file(base64_decode($ImageTmpPath),$UploadPath);`